# Does Flutter app need camera permissions before submitting for store?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, imagepicker

Does google play requires camera permission in a app..I've used camera with Image picker but it  asks access permissions for storage only.But Image picker can access camera.Do I need to add permissions for access camera manually before publishing app to play store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to explicitly set permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for `image_picker` package, thanks to `ContentProvider` in Android. You're good to go.

Comment: If we want to add permission is there any way to do it ?

Comment: @Cordelia Yes, you can add the permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file